# Disable ClickListener event

Tags: java, android, events, click

I set up several ClickListener events (using the setOnClickListener function). Now I'd like to disable (or deactivate, remove, delete) some of them temporarily and I can't find a way to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, I am using Android SDK 2.3

Comment: What does it mean 'temporarily'? could you just comment them and uncomment when you need them againg?

Comment: can you get `boolean` flags? for the events on which you want to disable that click event? If answer is yes you can call something like this: `public void setOnClickListener(....){ if(canProceed){ perform your procedure here}}` you can make `canProceed=false` on the events you want to disable the listeners. and than on your convenience you can make it true.

Comment: Of course, I could comment / uncomment the event using a flag, but in ActionScript you have the option to remove an event listener, which I think is very useful. I was wondering if such an option exists for the Android SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `setOnClickListener(null)`.

Comment: This compiles, but doesn't change the click event behavior. :-(

Comment: @user544659: It should. The source code shows that it nulls out the internal data member used for holding the listener.